Set Git submodules to point to branch head
I have multiple repos for my plaintext notes, and then I have a index repo that has all of them as submodules. Unlike submodules for code, I don't want them to be "pinned" to specific commit, I want them always on the head of their branch.
I can get quite close with git submodules update --remote, but I'd need to have "Updated submodule" commits, with I think are ugly and don't want.
I could just the ignore the modified: submodule (new commits) messages and never commit updates, and each time I clone the repo run git submodules update --remote, but this feels wrong and hacky.
Basically I want the index repo to not care about the state of the submodule, and when cloned default to the head of the branch.
Is this possible, I have looked around the book, reference and web (maybe I'm using the wrong keywords)?
StackOverflow suggested this question as it is almost the same: with git submodules, can I always get branch/HEAD when cloning? (unfortunately unanswered).

Just a note, from a programmer's perspective, your requirements don't make sense and that's probably also the reason you won't be able to achieve this with Git. Point is, Git is all about versioning, which in turn is about reproducing things exactly. Now, your approach to "just give me the latest version" contradicts the goal of reproducability, because "latest version" is something volatile.

I know Git is not made for this use case, but there could be a solution out there meant for something else but that could work for this.

Not submodules or subtrees. Google's [tag:repo] tool, maybe. Or may be multi-repo tool from https://myrepos.branchable.com/

Sorry if I missed the point here, but it looks like you're just trying to eliminate the " (new commits)" note that git status prints for update --remote'd submodules. Was it something else?

The question is more of if there is a better way to do it, because of that message and cloning the repo not returning the up to date submodules by default, I felt that maybe there would be a better way.

Well, there's two ways to do it: checkout gets you the committed history, or checkout gets you the latest tip for selected submodule histories but the committed version of the main project and any submodules you didn't mark for the latest-and-greatest treatment.  I don't see that there's any intrinsic "better" here. I do think the default for checkout should be to check out what was committed. I don't get how you'd view a notice saying you've got a newer version of a submodule checked out than what was committed is somehow derogatory, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing.

It does works, but since I didn't want the "updated submodule" commits, it felt weird to be hundreds (or the commit count on the submodule) of commits behind of what was at the time of the submodule add. Thanks for the discussion though, I feel I understand the problem better now.

Today I realised that symlinks are exactly what I want! I does mean I need to clone each subrepo manualy (or write a script) but after that I works perfectly! I'll test for a few days and then answer my own question. Thanks UlrichEckhardt, phd and jthill.

git submodule add or git submdule set-branch the submodule to a specific branch, git submodule update --remote  uses whatever's registered there. See git help submodule for more details but that should be enough to get going and might be all you need.
edit: I don't understand

I can get quite close with git submodules update --remote, but I'd need to have "Updated submodule" commits, with I think are ugly and don't want.

if you don't want status to check for submodule changes tell it ignore them, git status --ignore-submodules=all.

Strange answer. The OP rejected the approach right in the question.

Yeah, it made so little sense to me that the question could be about silencing a "this isn't the recorded commit" notice that I just blanked on it.
